# Keep data in html form after form submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

i was trying to keep the input in html form field after submission occur. so, i've used like

```
<input type="text" name="myField" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField']) ? $_POST['myField'] : 'column_name' ?>" />
```

its working nicely if input type is `text`. its not working with `<textarea>` & `<select>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For textarea:

```
<textarea><?php echo isset($_POST['myField']) ? $_POST['myField'] : 'column_name' ?></textarea>
```

For select:

```
<select>
   <option value='xx' <?php echo isset($_POST['myField'])&&$_POST['myField']=='xx'?'selected="selected"':''?>>XX</option>
   <option value='yy' <?php echo isset($_POST['myField'])&&$_POST['myField']=='yy'?'selected="selected"':''?>>YY</option>
</select>
```

If you have are using jQuery, I prefer to populate the select using javascript:

```
<select name='myField'>
    <option value='xx'>XX</option>
    <option value='yy'>YY</option>
</select>
<?php if(isset($_POST['myField'])):?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("select[name=myField] option[value='<?php echo $_POST['myField']';?>']").attr("selected","selected");
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`<textarea>`s don't have a `value` attribute.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-textarea-element.html#the-textarea-element) They have a body:

```
<textarea name="myField2"><?php echo isset($_POST['myField2']) ? $_POST['myField2'] : 'column_name' ?></textarea>
```

Likewise, [`<select>`s do not have a `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-select-element.html#the-select-element). The value of a `<select>` is determined by the contained `<option>`s which have [the `selected` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-option-element.html#attr-option-selected). This one is left as an exercise to the reader. Hint: you'll need to iterate over the `<select>`'s `<option>`s and conditionally add the `selected` attribute to one or more of the `<option>`s.