# prevent checkbox from getting reset after submit

Tags: php, laravel-4, get

Hi i am developing an laravel application and i have a form like shown below

```
<div class="row form-wrapper">
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="get" autocomplete="off" name="calculateform" id="calculateform" >
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Year') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                   <label for="Year" class="col-md-3 control-label calculate-label">@lang('admin/calculate2014/form.Calculate_dep')</label>
                   <?php
                        global $Year;
                        $years = array();
                        for ($i = 2013; $i < 2050; $i++)
                        {                       
                          $years[] = $i;
                        } 

                        echo '<select name="Year" class="controls assettext select2 selectyear" id="Year"  >';
                        echo '<option value="">-- Select Year --</option>';
                        foreach($years as $option)
                        {
                            echo "<option value='{$option}'";
                            if (isset($_GET['Year'])) { if ($_GET['Year'] == $option) { echo 'selected'; } }
                            echo ">{$option}</option>";   
                        }  
                        echo "</select>";

                   ?>
                       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-flat gray nextbtn" id ="next" value="Proceed"  />    

                        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('recalculate') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                          <label for="nesd" class="col-md-3 control-label recallabel">Recalculate</label>
                             <div class="controls col-md-7">
                                <input name="recalculate" type="checkbox" id="recalculate" value="yes" class="recalculate recalbtn"  >
                                {{ $errors->first('recalculate', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
                             </div>
                        </div>

                     <?php
                        if($_GET)
                        {   
                           echo'<br/>';
                           echo'<br/>';
                           echo'<br/>';
                           $Year =$_GET['Year']; 
                        }           
                     ?>  

                   {{ $errors->first('Year', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
        </div>

                <div  class="proceedhide" id="caution" >
                   <span class="alert-msg cautionmsg"><b>Caution:</b>Be careful if recalculate is checked the database will be refreshed.</span>
                </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here i am trying to pass a value from checkbox and pass it to a function,on clicking the submit button.The value gets passed through url and again the checkbox value gets refreshed.

How do i avoid the checkbox from being refreshed after the php page getting submitted.I tried the possible duplicate of this question but none of them worked.

Please help me to achieve this......

I tried below with no luck it shows Undefined Index:recalculate.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="recalculate" value="yes" <?php echo ($_GET['recalculate']=='yes' ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?> />
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a small remark. If you want to echo a php function inline you can write it shorter, like: <?=($_GET['recalculate]=='yes') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?>

Comment: change yes to on for checking if recalculate is checked and also check if value is isset for prevent warnings (isset($_GET['recalculate']))

`<input type="checkbox" name="recalculate" value="yes" <?php echo ($_GET['recalculate']=='On' ? 'checked="checked"' : '');?> />`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep data in html form after form submitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737013/keep-data-in-html-form-after-form-submitted)

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden Only if short tags are enabled. Bad practice, if you need to move your code to another server, where you have no controll over php.ini and short tags are not enabled.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Oh I thought most servers support short tags? But I can see it's a problem when a server doesn't support them..

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden This question is really divisive. You can read a long discussion about this here, on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `value="yes"`and then check if it's on:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="recalculate" <?php echo(isset($_GET['recalculate']) && $_GET['recalculate']=='on')?"checked":""?>>
```

Comment: i tried the above code it shows Undefined Index:recalculate.

Comment: hmm, maybe add the isset() method so it becomes:
<input type="checkbox" name="recalculate" <?php echo(isset($_GET['recalculate'] && $_GET['recalculate']=='on')?"checked":""?>>

Comment: I tried this and got "Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="recalculate" value="yes" <?php if($_GET['recalculate']=='yes') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> />
```

Comment: i tried the above code it shows Undefined Index:recalculate.

Comment: @Arul, Its just a warning.Just do one thing please define `recalculate` first then use in your code.